# How would I access the ScrollController in another dart file?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement a functionality to hide the **BottomNavigationBar** when my **SingleChildScrollView** is scrolled , but my **SingleChildScrollView** widget is not in the same dart file as the **BottomNavigationBar**.

I created the **ScrollController** and an array containing some pages -> my scrollable list is in **TasksList()**

```
late ScrollController scrollController;
//more logic
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

scrollController = ScrollController();
}

@override
void dispose() {
 scrollController.dispose();

 super.dispose();
}


final screens = [
TasksList(),
AddTodoPage(),
AddTodoPage(), ];
```

For the **bottomNavigationBar** I used a widget called **CurvedNavigationBar** which essentially styles the default nav bar. Everytime I tap on an item the index counts up and changes the screen:

```
bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
          key: navigationkey,
          color: LightColors.kYellowPrimary,
          buttonBackgroundColor: LightColors.kDarkerYellow,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          height: 60,
          animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
          animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 450),
          index: index,
          items: items,
          onTap: (index) => setState(() {
            this.index = index;
          }),
        ),
        body: screens[index],
```

The **TasksList** contains a **Scaffold** which contains my list:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
//List
```

How would I access the **ScrollController** that was created in the file with **BottomNavigationBar**, in the file that contains the list? Is there a way to access the ScrollController globally?

Answer (score -2):

Your question does not contain enough info, but I could give a few pointers:

- First, you could get scrollController without specifying it via `PrimaryScrollController.of(context)`, which is default one for root scrollViews on the screen, or when scrollView has flag primary set to **true**.
- Second, you could create your scrollController higher than both scrollView(SingleChildScrollView in your case) and navBar on the tree, in the widget inserting navBar add listener to its position and insert/remove navBar based on it.
- Third, you could listen to scroll notifications with `NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>` widget, just insert it into tree and trigger state changes based on notification contents.
- Fourth, you can access current scroll position with `Scrollable.of(context).position` and rebuild your tree based on its value.

I've given pointers, hope it helps to build your ui and experience with ways to handle scrollable widgets.